# Vue.js com Electron: imagens não são carregadas. "Images and other types of assets omitted"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, vuetify

Acabei de configurar um projeto com Vue.js e Electron usando [Electron Builder](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/) e ao rodar npm run electron:serve (vue-cli-service electron:serve) o logo do Vuetify (logo.png) que está na pasta "assets" não é carregado.

No console do terminal aparece o erro "Images and other types of assets omitted". Mas porque está sendo omitido? Alguma ideia de qual é a configuração envolvida?

```
No console do electron aparece o erro: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". A URL buscada é http://localhost:8080/.
```

Log completo do console do node:

```
PS C:\Users\Lucas_Pletsch\OneDrive\own-time> npm run electron:serve
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> own-time@0.1.0 electron:serve
> vue-cli-service electron:serve

 INFO  Starting development server...


 DONE  Compiled successfully in 4442ms                                                                                             08:07:14


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  - Network: http://192.168.1.105:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.

|  Bundling main process...

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2178ms                                                                                             08:07:17
  File                      Size                                                  Gzipped   

  dist_electron\index.js    801.57 KiB                                            175.88 KiB

  Images and other types of assets omitted.
  Build at: 2022-07-25T11:07:17.323Z - Hash: a01c9d543f7732d458ce - Time: 2178ms

 INFO  Launching Electron...
(node:20408) ExtensionLoadWarning: Warnings loading extension at C:\Users\Lucas_Pletsch\AppData\Roaming\own-time\extensions\ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg:
  Unrecognized manifest key 'browser_action'.
  Unrecognized manifest key 'update_url'.
  Permission 'contextMenus' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
  Cannot load extension with file or directory name _metadata. Filenames starting with "_" are reserved for use by the system.
(Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> Images and other types of assets omittedImages and other types of assets omitted
    insira o código aqui
```

Package.json:

```
[![{
  "name": "own-time",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "electron": "^13.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": \[
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    \],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": \[
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  \]
}

    insira o código aqui][1]][1]
```

[image: Estrutura do projeto:]

O logo é importado no App.vue:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código de onde você importa essa imagem/logo ?

Comment: @VictorBier coloquei.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acabei recriando o projeto, e após ter criado o app (vue create meuapp) e adicionado o electron builder (vue add electron-builder), adicionei o vuetify (antes eu tinha feito isso antes do electron builder)e aí carregou certo com vuetify.